# Yeoman generator error - ENOENT: no such file or directory on windows

Tags: windows, npm, yeoman, yeoman-generator, yeoman-generator-angular

Following packages installed on my win 10 64-bit machine:

```
C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm
+-- bower@1.8.0
+-- generator-aspnet-angular@0.0.1
+-- generator-aspnetcore-spa@0.8.1
+-- generator-hottowel@0.4.1
+-- grunt-cli@1.2.0
+-- gulp@3.9.1
+-- gulp-concat@2.6.0
+-- gulp-uglify@1.5.3
`-- yo@1.8.5
```

Trying to run the generator aspnet-angular, I get the following error:

```
yo aspnet-angular

     _-----_     ╭──────────────────────────╮
    |       |    │    Welcome to the cool   │
    |--(o)--|    │ generator-aspnet-angular │
   `---------´   │        generator!        │
    ( _´U`_ )    ╰──────────────────────────╯
    /___A___\   /
     |  ~  |
   __'.___.'__
 ´   `  |° ´ Y `

? Your project name AngularAspNetGenerator
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Development\AngularAspNetGenerator\Web.config'
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:640:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:508:33)
    at Object.readFileAsString (C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator-aspnet-angular\node_modules\html-wiring\index.js:281:13)
    at child.writing (C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator-aspnet-angular\generators\app\index.js:30:32)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator-aspnet-angular\node_modules\yeoman-generator\lib\base.js:431:23)
    at C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator-aspnet-angular\node_modules\run-async\index.js:25:25
    at C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator-aspnet-angular\node_modules\run-async\index.js:24:19
    at C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator-aspnet-angular\node_modules\yeoman-generator\lib\base.js:432:9
    at runCallback (timers.js:649:20)
```

New to yeoman and not having much luck so far. Can anyone help?

Comment: Looks like a bug with generator-aspnet-angular. It's been reported here https://github.com/lidia-freitas/generator-aspnet-angular/issues/1 - Honestly it just looks like this generator has just never been maintained by anyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a bug with the generator you used https://github.com/lidia-freitas/generator-aspnet-angular/issues/1

I'd recommend searching generators on https://npms.io/search?q=yeoman-generators and try to stay to the generator who're maintained. There's a lot of people publishing broken open source packages, so if you want to save some time, it's always better to make sure a project is well maintained before using it :)

Comment: Thanks for the information. Useful to know about the search too.